# How to return to original intent after user says Repeat during an elicit dialog on Alexa using Node js?

Tags: node.js, echo, alexa-skills-kit

Intents:

IntentA

This is the scenario:

- U: "Alexa, open myapp"
- A: "Welcome to myapp" (LaunchHandler)
- U: "Search routes" (IntentAHandler)
- A: "From where do you depart?" (IntentAHandler, with addElicitSlotDirective)
- U: "Repeat" (RepeatHandler)
- A: **"From where do you depart?" (IntentAHandler, with addElicitSlotDirective) <- I can't get to
  this**

I've tried different ways to return to the original intent, but I get this error:
**INVALID_RESPONSE A valid slot of the intent being processed should be specified for slotToElicit in "Dialog.ElicitSlot" directive**

The code from RepeatIntent:

```
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent = attributes.temp_IntentA;
return custom.IntentAHandler.handle(handlerInput);
```

I have no problem repeating the last speech, like when I have the output speech with results. But during a dialog, eliciting, how?
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

During a multi turn conversation with Dialog Model, the **intent remains the same** while the slots are getting filled or during the confirmation of intents/slots. Now when the user says *"Repeat"*, Alexa map it to `RepeatIntent` (unless you have *"repeat"* as utterance in the same intent). Now what you want is to elicit a slot of a different intent(original intent) from the handler of repeat intent. Unfortunately as of now you can't do this. Only **updated intent of same type** can be sent with a `Dialog.ElicitSlot` directive.

> Note that you cannot change intents when returning a Dialog directive,
>   so the intent name and set of slots must match the intent sent to your
>   skill.

You will receive an error message if you try to do so.

---

The solution is to

1. Save the state and progress made so far with `IntentA`.
2. (`RepeatIntent` or any other intent is called and response is sent)
3. Re-trigger the original `IntentA` with an appropriate utterance.
4. Restore the state and progress made.

You can save the state in `sessionAttributes` and to re trigger the `IntentA` you have to provide some utterance that will trigger it. In your case something like

```
"I would like to depart from {city}"

or just (if it doesn't break your VUI)

"{city}"
```

This way you the user can switch context in middle of a conversation and comeback easily. Once the intent is re-triggered you can use any Dialog model directives.

Read [this](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/d8579cd6-9109-42b2-ada6-df017fc1dee5/how-to-handle-different-intent-requests-with-dialog-management) blog post for more info about context switching.
More on Dialog Interface [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html).

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for this and after searching for hours I could not find exactly what I needed. After reading through several posts and articles I got what I needed. I joined together the bits and pieces to implement the Amazon.RepeatIntent by using Request and Response Interceptors. I wrote a blog post on this in details for this. You can check the post [here](http://%20https://medium.com/@udaydhadve/how-to-tell-alexa-to-remember-and-repeat-a-response-in-your-alexa-custom-skill-part-1-of-2-db69bbd3df41).